# Count from list in ruby

Tags: ruby, list, count

Im thinking this is correct, but probably WAY off.

I have a string formatted as such
name, name1, name2, name3, name4, etc

```
admins_count = 0
if ["name2", "name3"].include?(player_list)
  admins_count += 1
end
```

Is this the proper way to count matches in a list?

Essentially, its a list of players, I want to count how many of the names in the second list mtch against player_list.

this is what worked for me a combo of things

```
player_list = response[3].split(" ", 2)[1].chomp[1..-2]
admin_list = "Howard_Roark, Gerrit8500, fffizzz"
mod_list = "ZionRx, rodtang, fuzzamuzza, DJRedFlames, bingbong2715, ErebusAnima, Twentytenor2, zephyrnug, Tiberione, deadkill02, tTheoRyy, PyneApll, tercept, Hestehaven, Orjis87, Yaltar101"

mod_arr = mod_list.split(", ")
admin_arr = admin_list.split(", ")
player_arr = player_list.split(", ")

mods_count = 0
mod_arr.each do |s|
        mods_count += 1 if player_arr.include? s
end

admins_count = 0
admin_arr.each do |s1|
        admins_count += 1 if player_arr.include? s1
end

puts "players.value #{player_count}"
puts "mods.value #{mods_count}"
puts "admins.value #{admins_count}"
```

Comment: what's `player_list`? a string? an array of strings?

Comment: DO you have a **string** as `"name, name1, name2"` and on or do you have an **array of strings** such as `["name", "name1", "name2"]`?
Also, WHAT is `player_list`?
What exactly do you expect to achieve?
Give us some more info, please!

Comment: player_list is a string from an array  player_list = response[3].split(" ", 2)[1].chomp[1..-2]------------- that being said, the output of player_list is exactly as described above name1, name2, name3, name4, name5. I need to check that list and count the matches from the second list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is more of what you want:

```
formatted_string = "name,name1,name2,name3,name4";
string_arr = formatted_string.split(",")

string_arr.each do |s|
   admin_count += 1 if player_list.include? s
end
```

Comment: `string_arr.count {|s| player_list.include? s }`

Answer (score 1):

If `player_list` is an Array, you could use the [`&` operator](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-26). It takes two Arrays and returns a new Array of only the items the two Arrays have in common (with no duplicates).

```
# I'm assuming player_list becomes a string of 'name1, name2, name3...' after 
# the 'chomp' method
player_list = response[3].split(" ", 2)[1].chomp[1..-2].split(",").map(&:strip)
admins_count = (["name2", "name3"] & player_list).size
```

So, if `player_list` contains "name2" then it will return `["name2"]`. We then call `.size` on that and we would get `1` which would get assigned to `admins_count`.

Comment: I want to return a count of matches from the formatted string, vs player_list, not the match itself. Its for a munin plugin im trying to modify and I know nothing about ruby, sorry for noob questions.

Comment: That's what the `size` at the end of the expression is. The expression in the `()` will return the matches and the `.size` is then called on the matches Array getting the count of items in it.

Comment: I had a parse error when trying this, let me set it up again and ill post it.something about the &

Comment: :in `&': can't convert String into Array (TypeError)

Comment: Ah, I read your comment about it being a string from an array in which case you should use the way @Hunter did to `.split(",")` the String up into an Array. Maybe even do a `.strip` on it to get rid of any whitespace. An Array really is the best way to compare two groups of items.

Comment: I updated my answer to take that into account. Since you are just getting into Ruby, ignore at the moment why `map(&:strip)` works and just know that it is calling the method `strip` on every item in your Array to make sure there is no whitespace. =)